# extension scalars of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K\to L$ be an arbitrary field extension. $K$ has characteristic zero. Let $X$ be a variety over $K$. Let $Y=X\times_K spec L$.

1)Is it true that $Y$ is reduced?

2)Let $Y=\cup Y_i$ be decomposition into irreducible components. We have the natural maps $Y_i\to X$. Is it true that these maps are dominant?

I know that $Y\to X$ is flat, but it is not necessary of finite type.

Comment: 1. Does "variety" include the condition "reduced" for you? 2. What is $Y_i$? Is it an irreducible component, an open subset, what?

Comment: 1. Yes variety is necessary reduced. 2. I edited. $Y_i$ are irreducible components.

Comment: If $L/K$ is finite then 1) follows from this stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/033B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $X$ is a reduced $K$-scheme of finite type, then exercise 3.15, chapter II in Hartshorne (or QingLiu proposition 2.7, chapter II), shows that TFAE:

- $X \times_K \overline{K}$ is reduced with $\overline{K}$ algebraic closure.
- $X \times_K K^p$ is reduced with $K^p$ perfect closure.
- $X \times_K L$ is reduced for any extesion $L/K$.

In your case, $K^p=K$ (any perfect field, not necessarily of characteristic zero) and $X = X \times_K K^p$ is reduced, we know that $X \times_K L$ is reduced for all $L/K$.

2. This is not true in general. For instance, take $X  = X_1 \sqcup X_2$ with $X_1,X_2$ geometrically integral (being integral after any extension of fields), then $X_L = (X_1)_L \sqcup (X_2)_L$; by exercise 3.15 in Hartshorne again, $(X_1)_L,(X_2)_L$ are irreducible and the map $(X_1)_L \to X$ is never dominant because the image does not contain the generic point of $X_2$.

It is true however, if you assume that $X$ is irreducible. You can consult [Lemma 33.8.10](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0364) on StackProject (I think it is more or less same as proposition 2.6 in QingLiu but I have not checked).

Comment: Well, a variety is irreducible by definition(maybe not necessarily geometrically).

Comment: @Galoisgroup, it depends on the author, lots of people define a variety to be a separated scheme of finite type, some would put reducedness and some put irreducibility in the definition.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.